Extract text between <br> into a dictionary
I'm trying to extract text and group it from the html like this example:
<p>                 
<strong>
Mrs. Karina TARGUS, Deputy Head of Mission &amp; Chargé d'affaires, a.i.<br>
</strong>
&nbsp;&nbsp; and Mrs. Joanna Brien<br>
                                
            
Carmen Maria
OLIVEIRA, <strong>Minister-Counsellor</strong><br>
            
Jonathan
SMITH, <strong>Counsellor</strong><br>
            
Matthias
MELLER, <strong>Counsellor</strong><br>
</p>

Is there a good way to get this? I can use commas to separate name from role.
extracted = {"Mrs. Karina TARGUS":"Deputy Head of Mission &amp; Chargé d'affaires", "and Mrs. Joanna Brien":"", "Carmen Maria OLIVEIRA":"Minister-Counsellor", "Jonathan SMITH":"Counsellor", "Matthias MELLER":"Counsellor"}


Split by br and then split by comma? It's not really clear what format do you want and whether that format can even be expressed in code.
